# Unnecessary vspace for align/equation when it's first on page

Tags: math-mode, equations, vertical-alignment, align

I'm using the align environment and now I have the problem that one of my formulas is the first object on a page with some vspace before it. But this looks a bit odd, because it isn't in line with the text of the previous page. Trying to use `\vspace{-xcm}` seems to have no effect. The same holds true for the `equation` environment, but there with not so much vspace.

How could I delete this unnecessary vspace and align the formula on top of the page where normal text would be?

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrbook} 

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \newpage
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \newpage
    \begin{align}
                \intertext{Objective function}
                \min x \\
                \intertext{s.t.} 
        x < 5 \\
        x > 2 
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{-\abovedisplayskip}`; but it's better not starting a paragraph (or a page) with a display.

Comment: A page hardly ever start with a formula. So why are you doing this in the first place?

Comment: @daleif I shortened my question. The long version is a mathematical program with an align environment starting with a `\shorttext{}` command. So the page doesn't really start with a formula but with that text followed by the objective function. I could have exclude that text from the align environment, but I wanted to keep them together in one environment.

Comment: Please update the mwe to reflect this. I still do not see what the problem is.

Comment: @daleif Please have a look at the updated MWE. You see that the word `Objective function` is not at the top of the third page and not in line with the text of page 2. As I mentioned it would be possible to just write the two words before the align environment, but I wanted the complete program in just one environment.

Comment: Drop `Objective...` outside. `\intertext` is meant to be between lines, thus there is spacing above and below. Besides, generally a displayed equation should not start a page, which is why LaTeX goes to great length for that not to happen.

Comment: Next time please be more specific in mentioning that you are comparing page 2 and 3 side by side. That is not obvious from your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `\intertext` to start the display. And you're better using `\shortintertext` in the second case, in order to reduce the vertical spacing.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\newpage
\lipsum[1-3]
\newpage
Objective function
\begin{align}
\min x \\
\shortintertext{s.t.}
x < 5 \\
x > 2
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A display should *never* start a paragraph (nor be the first thing on a page).